# Validate form with multiple fields using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a form in SharePoint list form's `newform.aspx` with  40+ fields and on submit button click , i need to perform the validation of these fields.
I am writing inside the SP Designer like below:

```
   function PreSaveAction()
       {
      var fnamevalthrusputility = 
     SPUtility.GetSPField('fisrt name').GetValue();
       if(fnamevalthrusputility == null || 
      fnamevalthrusputility.length === 0)
    {
       flagG =false;
      //$("input[title='first name']
      //").css('border-color','red');
     alert('Enter first name.');
    }
     custid = SPUtility.GetSPField('Customer ID').GetValue();
    if(custid == null || custid.length === 0)
    {
     flagG =false;
        // document.contactinfo.Name.style.border="solid 1px red";
        //jQuery("input[Title='Customer ID Required 
       field']").css("border","solid             1px red"); 
        alert('Enter Customer ID.');
    }

    if(flagG == false)
    {
        alert('please fill mandatory fields');
        return false;
    }
   else
       {
       //  alert('Valdiations are done! Going to save the form //with a 
      //  new id  in the database');
     return true;
      }
```

but when it comes multiple fields, I need to show a common error message which has all the field which are throwing error, ie either its empty of not-selected value from the dropdown field etc.
Currently I am showing it different `alert` messages for each field that's validated.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `required` and `pattern` attributes on elements

Comment: Try to take a common global variable to fill with all these errors at every step ie- change it's value, and then after all the process put it in a single alert function. you'll get the exact results.

Comment: Akshaya, can you please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: like `var message = ""; if(condion1){message+="some error message"}` `else if(condition2){message+="another type of error"}` `else{message+="suppose last error"}` then at last you may `alert(message);`

Comment: Let me work on this and revert.Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Is there a reason your not using column validation on each item?  if you use SharePoint's built in column validation you don't need to add code and you can do exactly what your trying to.

Comment: I have some 70+ fields in my list form and some around 50 fields require validation,so thought of going ahead with the help of javascript ,spservices, sputility js files instead of existing column validation.